# How to change the map scale units for ArcGIS Online printable maps?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-online, scale, arcgis-web-appbuilder, units

I have a web app created from the ArcGIS Online Basic View template. I added print functionality to the web app as seen in figure 1. You can see in figure 2 the scale units are set to miles/kilometers by default in the printable map. Is there a way to convert the units of measurement in the print map scale to feet and/or meters?

**Figure 1**

[image]

**Figure 2**

[image]

Comment: Is that print service coming from your ArcGIS Server?

Comment: It is coming from The ArcGIS online cloud service.